# Can I create a mock service for a card transaction workflow that bypasses the need for the physical card machine to test?

Tags: .net, testing, postman, specflow, azurite

I have a card payment work flow that utilizes multiple API endpoints in it's workflow to start a transaction ask the customer if they are paying with card/cash prompts the user to tap the card payment device to take a payment and then completes the transaction and prints a receipt.

The device is a third party but for the card payment request endpoint when making the call to Postman it requires the user to tap the device for the endpoint to go through and return a successful response.

Is there a way for me to create a Mock Service using a library such as Specflow along side a Postman script to test the workflow end to end ***locally*** to bypass the need of using the device.

I am currently using Cosmos Emulator and Azurite to test the endpoints locally.

Comment: I don't think we have enough information to answer your question. You'll need to reverse engineer what that device is doing which forces you to tap it. Perhaps you make some API call to a service, which then is configured to make a call to the device. Then the device waits for the user to tap the screen before the device makes a call back to the service to confirm the payment. That is not an easy thing to "mock".